# React-Router: simple route not displayed for navigation even though it is defined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following two components: `Dashboard` and `Profile`. These are rendered for respective routes as I have defined below:

```
<Route exact path="/:userId" component={ Profile }/>
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={ Dashboard }/>
```

The problem is, when I navigate to `"/dashboard"`, the `Profile` component is always rendered. I am expecting that navigation to `"/dashboard"` would show `Dashboard` based on my routing above.

How to fix this case?

Comment: please post your code, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `Profile` is shown instead of `Dashboard` is because the pattern of `/:userId` (ie for the profile route) matches the path `/dashboard`.

Because your `Profile` route is declared before the `Dashboard` route, the `Profile` route consumes/renders the request. That means the `Dashboard` route is never reached or rendered.

A simple fix would be to swap the declaration of these `<Route>` components like so:

```
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={ Dashboard }/>
<Route exact path="/:userId" component={ Profile }/>
```

Comment: Tks @Dacre again, I checked ur fix. Next time, i'll  better to write title and description for my question